# Can I Delete a WhatsApp Message After 7 Min. Deadline?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, delete

So I know that if I send a WhatsApp message to someone, I can delete the message on the recipients phone within 7 minutes, using the new "[delete for everyone](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000068/)" option in WhatsApp.

Is there a way to get passed this limit, and delete the message a few hours or days later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a simple way to trick WhatsApp into thinking that 7 min. haven't passed yet.

This would involve A few simple steps.
(Note: this will only work within 5 days of sending the message)

1. **disconnect WhatsApp from internet connection.** You can do that by going into airplane mode, or disconnecting from mobile data and WiFi.
2. **Change the date of your phone.** in *settings -> date and time* turn off "automatic date and time" and change the date to within 7 min. of sending the message or even before that.
   (If you sent a message on nov. 20 at 7:30, then just change the date on your phone, to nov. 19)
3. **Force stop the WhatsApp app**. Go to settings>apps>WhatsApp>force stop.
4. **delete the message.** Open WhatsApp and find the message that you want to delete, long press on it and now the "delete for everyone" option will appear, press on it.
5. **Change the date back to normal**
6. **Turn off airplane mode or enable data/WiFi**

As soon as WhatsApp gets network connection, the message will be deleted on the recipients phone. But you will not get any notification that it was deleted.

If for whatever reason there is a red exclamation mark next to the message, make sure you changed the time, and then press on the exclamation mark and press "resend message" that will delete for the recipient.